# How to calculate average in intraday trading of NSE/NIFTY equity shares?

Tags: india, trading, day-trading, nse-india, value-averaging

I am beginner in intraday trading of NSE equity shares in Zerodha. Sometimes I have failed to calculate the average  when I trade  the same shares multiple times during the same day.  For example:

**During morning hours:**

If I bought 1,000 number of HDFC shares at 500/- and it rose to 505/- in 5 minutes and I  sold, my profit would be (1000*5=5000).

**During afternoon hours:**

If again I bought 2,000  HDFC shares at 490/- and it rose to 494/- in 10 minutes and I sold, my profit should be (2000*4=8000).

So the total profit for the day is 5K+ 8K= 13K  but my calculation is wrong. I do not see  13K.  I see something less than that. What is the correct calculation?

If possible explain for below scenarios as well

### Scenario-1

1. Morning: Sale-buy
2. Afternoon: Buy-sale

### Scenario-2

1. Morning:Buy-sale
2. Afternoon: sale-buy

### Scenario-3

1. Morning: Sale-Buy(short)
2. Afternoon: sale-buy(short)

Comment: "I do not see 13K. I see something less than that." What do you see? Please provide the exact trades, what you calculated as the profit, and what was reported.

Answer (score 1):

> For example if i bought 1000 number of HDFC shares at 500/- and it gave a spike of 515/- in a 5 minutes, i sold. so my profit would be (1000*5=5000).

1,000 x 15 = 15,000 not 5,000

> If again i brought same 2000 number of HDFC shares at 490/- and its gave spike of 494/- in 10 minutes , i sold. i expected my profit should be (2000*4=8000).

2,000 x 4 = 8,000

The total is 23,000

Deduct commissions and fees

Comment: Sorry. your answer not answered my question.

Comment: Your math was bad.  It's better now that you have edited out your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically 5000+8000 as you have already mentioned. But I think you might have forgot to consider the brokerage charges, other charges like STT etc., on every trade which normally depends on your broker, the plan you choose, amount of trade you have done etc., I suggest get in contact with customer care of Zerodha to know more about it.